# Distribution of coefficients arrived at by stochastic gradient descent?

Tags: distributions, optimization, stochastic-gradient-descent

In SGD we have update

$$w^{(k)} = w^{(k-1)} + \nabla _wL(y,w)$$

Hence $w^{(k)}$ is a sum of random variables.

They're not iid, so the central limit theorem doesn't apply. Is there some result, kind of like the central limit theorem, that tells us the distribution of $w$?

Comment: is this paper helpful? [Stochastic Gradient Descent as Approximate Bayesian Inference](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04289)

Comment: You don't actually need i.i.d. random variables for the CLT, the conditions are somewhat weaker.  They just need to be "independent enough", e.g., the covariance goes to zero fast enough as the difference between the indices gets larger, and don't need to be identical, see for example https://www.johndcook.com/blog/central_limit_theorems/.   Of course, none of this means that $\text{SGD} \implies w^{(k)} \xrightarrow{d} \text{Normal}$, but there is hope...